# Separating voices in an audio file

Tags: audio, core-audio

If there are two persons speaking in an audio file recorded by my phone, can I separate the two voices? If not completely, can I make one of them less noticable ?

Comment: its possible yet not easy ... google this ... audacity Separating voices in an audio file ... specifically https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/23807/is-it-possible-to-separate-voices-from-one-mp3-file

Comment: here on SO this question is extremely broad and vary far from a show-me-some-code-with-an-insightful-nugget-of-truth ... also SO frowns on questions asking advice ... please read up on the freq asked questions      How to Ask for Technical Help? Evidence-based Guidelines for Writing Questions on Stack Overflow
    https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ... also lookup :  Cocktail Party Problem ...    Oh and Welcome to SO

Comment: I'm voting to close as too broad but I'll give you a bread crumb: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_signal_separation

Comment: Blind source separation is a broad research topic.